# Jquery ajax is cutting the arrays?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I'm sending two arrays of data to laravel controller. Before sending the length of arrays is about **220 each**. Then for test I'm returning response in json back to jquery again with length of arrays and the first one is ok - 220 and the second array is ~114 length.

[image]

How can I solve it?

**Jquery ajax:**

```
    console.log('Array first before '+arr.length);
    console.log('Array second before '+arr_planned.length);

    $.ajax({
        method:'POST',
        url:url,
        data: {
            _token:token,
            arr:arr,
            arr_planned:arr_planned
        }
    }).done(function(msg) {
      console.log(msg);
    });
```

**Controller**

```
$array_normal = $request['arr'];
$array_planned = $request['arr_planned'];

return response()->json(['Array first after' => sizeof($array_normal),'Array second after' => sizeof($array_planned)],200);
```

**Edit**
I'm seeing right now that the array length is limited to 334 (based on other array test).

[image: Second image]

Comment: `return response()->json(['Array first after' => count($array_normal),'Array second after' =>count($array_planned)]);`check once

Comment: It's exactly the same response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very likely that the problem is how many variables are accepted in requests in your **php.ini** config.
You should uncomment the `;max_input_vars = 100` to something like `max_input_vars = 100000`.

Hope it'll help.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably hitting the PHP limits for maximum POST size or input variables. Create / edit a php.ini file in the root of your website and add

```
memory_limit = 256M
post_max_size = 150M
max_input_vars = 10000
```

You can check to see the limits have been implemented by adding `['memory_limit' => ini_get('memory_limit'), 'post_max_size' => ini_get('post_max_size'), 'max_input_vars' => ini_get('max_input_vars')]` to your response.

It could also possibly be a problem with the way PHP is handling that much data. It could be truncating it before reaching any limits defined. You can compare `$_POST` with `php://input`, which is the raw string data. You can use a function like this:

```
function getRealPOST() {
    $pairs = explode("&", file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $vars = array();
    foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
        $nv = explode("=", $pair);
        $name = urldecode($nv[0]);
        $value = urldecode($nv[1]);
        $vars[$name] = $value;
    }
    return $vars;
}

var_dump($_POST, getRealPOST());
```

If they are different then PHP is just having dificulties somewhere when populating `$_POST` and you can use that `getRealPOST` function as a work around.

Comment: Thanks! The problem was only max_input_vars.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.